# login vk.com net::http.post_form

Tags: ruby, http

I want login to vk.com or m.vk.com without Ruby. But my code dosen't work.

```
require 'net/http'

email = "qweqweqwe@gmail.com"
pass = "qeqqweqwe"

userUri = URI('m.vk.com/index.html')
Net::HTTP.get(userUri)
res = Net::HTTP.post_form(userUri, 'email' => email, 'pass' => pass)
puts res.body
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without Ruby", when you are clearly using Ruby?

Comment: ...and what do you mean by "doesn't work"? Did you get an error message? Often they have a big hint as to what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to change userUri to the following:

```
userUri = URI('https://login.vk.com/?act=login')
```

Which is where the vk site expects your login parameters.

I'm not very faimilar with vk, but you probably need a way to handle the session cookie. Both receiving it, and providing it for future requests. Can you elaborate on what you're doing after login?

Here is the net/http info for cookie handling:

```
# Headers
res['Set-Cookie']            # => String
res.get_fields('set-cookie') # => Array
res.to_hash['set-cookie']    # => Array
puts "Headers: #{res.to_hash.inspect}"
```

Answer (score 2):

This kind of task is exactly what Mechanize is for. Mechanize handles redirects and cookies automatically. You can do something like this:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
url = "http://m.vk.com/login/"

page = agent.get(url)

form = page.forms[0]
form['email'] = "qweqweqwe@gmail.com"
form['pass'] = "qeqqweqwe"
form.submit

puts agent.page.body
```